RSS functionality
Has RSS functionality been removed? I remember it being there, but haven't seen it for a while.
The docs say:
Navigate to Events > Manage Events.
Click on the orange and white square icon on the top right of the page.
Copy the URL to share or embed into your website.

but there's no icon.
Also, Past questions reference:

But my site (Joomla 4.4.8 & Civi 5.77.0) shows:

Which only downloads an ICS file.

It looks like it might have been removed here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23808. There's a lot of discussion there but nothing about rss.
Interestingly the code still supports rss you just need to add &list=1&rss=1 to the url that the download link gives, e.g. civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&rss=1

Hmm. https://URL/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&rss=1 gives me "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

I don't know much about joomla. You'd have to check the web server logs for the actual error. It works on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Sorted the server permission issues causing the 500 errors, thanks.
As you point out, 'the code still supports rss', and on the sandbox site produces a valid rss link
However, for my site, it produces invalid rss, because inserted before the first line of rss is:

This happens on a wordpress site too but not on the sandbox site. Any clue where that might be coming from?

Feeling rather silly, because I had not properly translated the Drupal path you provided into a Joomla path.
Thus, the RSS feed for Civi events on Joomla sites is accessible at:
https://HOST/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1&rss=1
I will seek the reinstatement of the RSS feed icon on the event management page.
